# why different servers give different $_FILES output?

Tags: php, apache, file, input

I've got a strange issue. I'm making a module to upload files. On the local server works properly. On the remote server, $_FILES reads file input data differntly. Particularly, on the remote server I get only fields I just valorized, while on the local server I get all the fields (even the ones already saved, and that's what I want).

Conditions are the same, same app, same files, same situation. Servers are both apache, but maybe with different configurations (I'm not a sys admin)

Local example:

```
["set_3"]=>
array(3) {
  ["banner0"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["banner1"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["banner2"]=>
  string(16) "test3-banner.jpg"
}
```

Remote example:

```
["set_3"]=>
array(1) {
  ["banner1"]=>
  string(16) "test2-banner.png"
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: We are gonna need a bit more info.. can you post the html & php blocks responsible for generating this array?

Comment: That's not $_FILES output, unless you're mangling it somehow after the fact.

Comment: please show the contents of `var_dump($_FILES)` as well, cheers

Comment: Are they running the same version of PHP?

Comment: @Nathan: remote server: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7, local server: 5.6.7 (but worked even with previous versions)

Comment: @Martin, Marc: yes, it's a piece of var_dump($_FILES). I can post all but it's really big. The one I posted is the piece with differencies.

Comment: Ok, fixed. I was able to replicate the problem even on local server: then it's not a server problem. I found a bug on my code. Thank you anyway!